# Show toast message from a thread in a class different than MainActivity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-toast

I've  just started to learn Android and tried to write a simple application. After button click, MP starts to play.

The code below works fine
 but I can't figure out how to show a toast message 
when an exception occurs in media players try-catch statements.

I'd like to keep the player thread in separate class for further experimenting .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static String url="http://stream001.radio.hu:8080/mr3.mp3";
static Activity context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context=this;
        //set button listener
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    myMediaPlayerClass.startMediaPlayer(url, context);
                }
            }
        );
    }
  ...   
}


public class myMediaPlayerClass {
    static MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();

    public static void startMediaPlayer(  final String myUrl, final Activity myContext){

        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
            string url=myUrl;
                Context context=myContext;
            //***********************************************
            // trying to Toast from here results in crash
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Thread running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //*********************************************************************
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            try {mp.setDataSource(url);} 
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
            catch (SecurityException e) {} 
            catch (IllegalStateException e) {} 
            catch (IOException e) {}

            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer paramMediaPlayer){}
                    });

            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {}
                });

        try {mp.prepare();} 
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {} 
        catch (IOException e) {}

        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
        mp.start();
            }   
    }).start();

    }
 }
```

Comment: You can't show a toast from a non-UI thread. Use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: use getApplicationContext() instead of context

Answer (score 1):

You can't show a toast from a non-UI thread directly. Yes you can do it but by implementing `runOnUiThread`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
```

Show Toast message on different thread...

Answer (score 0):

Use it in run() method

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"toast msg here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```